# String manipulation in Lua with special characters

Tags: string, lua, trim, lua-patterns

I would like to trim a string in Lua but I'm struggling I think because of the special characters in the string.

E.g. `str = "RG Ph 0%/15.00bpm"`

I would like to remove everything after and including the `"/"`

so that`str = "RG Ph 0%"`

I have found the following code but I don't think it handles the `"%"` and `"/"` properly:

```
local string_gsub = string.gsub

function string.trimRight( str, char )          
char = char or "%s"          
return ( string_gsub( str, "(" .. char .. "*)$", "" ) )  
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
local str = "RG Ph 0%/15.00bpm"
str = str:match'[^/]*'
print(str)
```